# In Jetpack Compose how can I make a TextField emit Accessibility events?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility

I am trying to make my app work with an other developers app that uses accessibility events to assist users with typing. I'm using Jetpack Compose 1.3.2. It seems that when text is changed for a TextField the AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED event it not emitted. How should this be handled?

```
var textFieldValue by remember {
    mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(""))
}
TextField(
    textFieldValue = textFieldValue,
    onValueChange = {
        textFieldValue = it
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doc: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/accessibility?hl=en-us

Demo Example:

```
@Composable
private fun PostMetadata(metadata: Metadata) {
  // Merge elements below for accessibility purposes
  Row(modifier = Modifier.semantics(mergeDescendants = true) {}) {
    Image(
      imageVector = Icons.Filled.AccountCircle,
      contentDescription = null // decorative
    )
    Column {
      Text(metadata.author.name)
      Text("${metadata.date} • ${metadata.readTimeMinutes} min read")
    }
  }
}
```

[image]